# ScrollViewer still visible when Height is 0

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

It is easy to reproduce. Just create a new project and paste the following code:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Name="Header" Height="0">
    <TextBlock Text="This text is hidden" />
    <ScrollViewer>
        <TextBlock Margin="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="32" Text="This text isn't."/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</StackPanel>
```

The question is the stact panel height is 0 thus the content is supposed to be invisible.
How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Just messing around with the settings.
Found that by adding the `CacheMode="BitmapCache"` to `Stackpanel` worked.
Googled it and it seems it is not recommend to do this way considering the performance.
Still looking for the proper answer;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the `StackPanel` invisible, set `Visibility` to  `Collapsed` instead. Or you wish to make the `ScrollViewer` invisible in certain cases?

Comment: I animated the StackPanel's Height Properties. Thus the height is changing from 0 to some value(or some to 0). But the scrollViewer doesn't hide. That's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to make the ScrollViewer and its content disappear when the height of the StackPanel goes to zero.  If that is the case, then just trigger off the SizeChanged event of the StackPanel to handle when you should show or hide the Scrollviewer.

```
    private void Header_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Header.Height.Equals(0))
        {
            scroller.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else
        {
            scroller.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
```